# Assigning a checked checkbox from a group to a PHP variable

Tags: php

I have an extremely basic knowledge of PHP so any help or links to relevant tutorials would be helpful.

I have three check boxes - 'Beginner', 'Intermediate' and 'Advanced'. I've written a bit of jQuery which means only one can be selected (like a radio button). I want to assign the one that is selected to a PHP variable to submit on a form, but I can't find any tutorials which help/I can understand. All the checkboxes share the same class. Would I loop through them and select the one that is checked? Any insight would be a great help.

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="generate_workout.php" target="_new">

    <div class="difficulty-check">
        <input type="checkbox" id="easy-check" class="difficulty" name="beginner"/>
        <label for="easy-check"></label>
    </div>

    <div class="difficulty-check">
        <input type="checkbox" id="medium-check" class="difficulty" name="intermediate"/>
        <label for="medium-check"></label>
    </div>

    <div class="difficulty-check">
        <input type="checkbox" id="hard-check" class="difficulty" name="advanced"/>
        <label for="hard-check"></label>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Generate"/>

</form>
```

Comment: Why don't you use radio buttons instead of check boxes with jQuery to limit the selection to one. Is it just for appearance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you name all the check boxes the same you will be able to access the value of the one that was submitted in PHP. For example, change all the name attributes of your check boxes to `level`. Instead of puttting beginner, intermediate, and advanced in the name attribute, but them in the value attribute.

```
<form method="post" action="generate_workout.php" target="_new">

    <div class="difficulty-check">
        <input type="checkbox" id="easy-check" class="difficulty" name="level[]" value="beginner" />
        <label for="easy-check"></label>
    </div>

    <div class="difficulty-check">
        <input type="checkbox" id="medium-check" class="difficulty" name="level[]" value="intermediate" />
        <label for="medium-check"></label>
    </div>

    <div class="difficulty-check">
        <input type="checkbox" id="hard-check" class="difficulty" name="level[]" value="advanced" />
        <label for="hard-check"></label>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Generate"/>

</form>
```

Then, when the form is submitted to `generate_workout.php` you can see which check box was submitted like so:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST['level']); //Returns an array of all the check boxes that were clicked
?>
```

Comment: thing is, what will happen if more than one is chosen? Answer: it will overwrite the other(s). radio buttons should be used, if only one choice is to be the option.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Didn't he say he did some jQuery so the user could only choose one? But yes, I agree, he should use radio buttons.

Comment: @blazerunner44 sure, but in not seeing the jQuery that goes with this, is hard to say. Even then, the checkboxes would still need to be treated as an array.

Comment: When I used labels for radio buttons similar to above, they didn't behave correctly. I could select more than one.

Comment: @ChrisWness I edited my answer to allow selecting more than one check box. `$_POST['level']` is now an array of all the check boxes that were selected.

Comment: Your original solution was perfect, but your edit will also be handy for the 'body parts' (I'm making a fitness website, in case it wasn't obvious by now ;) )